# Protobuf-net appears to box value types. Is that actually so?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

This came up at work today while profiling the app. I looked around, didn't find much yet. While the following question has nothing to do with what I ask, it does have a nice call stack.

[protobuf-net deserialization System.IO.EndOfStreamException under mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018627/protobuf-net-deserialization-system-io-endofstreamexception-under-mono)

Of the the lines there is exactly the one that pops in our stacks and have a quite high cost:

```
at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject (object,int,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader,System.Type) <0x00056>
```

Does this mean that all value types, specifically structs, are always boxed?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, interesting; it looks like *if you aren't fully compiling the model*, then yes: `SubItemSerializer` currently employs a "box, call back into `ReadObject`" strategy. I consider this a bug, so thanks for spotting it! This issue does not apply when fully compiling, as it uses a different strategy, so for now you might be able to solve it simply by preparing a model with the types you are interested in - for example:

```
static readonly TypeModel serializer;

static SomeType()
{
    var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
    model.Add(typeof(SomeRootType), true);    
    model.Add(typeof(SomeOtherRootType), true);
    // ...
    serializer = model.Compile();
}
```

(then use `serializer`, not the static `Serializer` utility, to serialize and deserialize)

I will investigate whether I can change `SubItemSerializer` to *inline* structs when it sees them.

---

Update: I *basically* have the inline working, but it has highlit some issues with stacks and branching, which are legal when separated by method boundaries, but not legal when the branch crosses a stack-line - I'm fixing that up too before I commit (basically, it involves introducing a few locals in some key places, rather than keeping things on the stack).

Comment: Marc, thank you for your help! Really appreciate. I'll try the workaround. Will be looking forward to the next release. If you don't mind, please add a comment here when it's ready.

Comment: @schultz will do; first i just need to make peverify happy. I get very upset when my CIL doesn't verify cleanly